# XMLHttpRequest is not defined in platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I get a XMLHttpRequest is not defined error with Angular2, Typescript, and NodeJS When I run command `ts-node main.ts`. 
This is my exception

```
D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\bundles\platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js:31
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                          ^
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at ResourceLoaderImpl.get (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\bundles\platform-bro
wser-dynamic.umd.js:31:27)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13753:47
)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateAsync (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler
.umd.js:13799:25)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.
js:13771:48)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\comp
iler.umd.js:18074:79)
    at D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18250:58
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\compile
r\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18249:45)
    at D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:27366:62
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:27365:47)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.um
d.js:27320:56)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:2728
6:25)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:8083:
29)
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (D:\workspace_git\nodejs\xgame\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:8058:25)
```

How to fix this bug.

Comment: I get this error from VS Code